# How can I get and display all values of a certain field in a sql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table wherein I need to get all the data in one column/field, but I can't seem to make it work with the code I have below:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from client");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result111);
echo $row['name'];
```

With the code above, it only prints one statement, which happens to be the first value in the table. I have 11 more data in the table and they are not printed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **`loop`** through the recordsets .. (A **`while`** loop will do) Something like this will help

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from client");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_fetch_array()` function will return the next element from the array, and it will return false when you have ran out of records. This is how you can use while loops to loop through the data, like so:

```
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // do something with the data...
    echo $record['column_name'];
}
```